# How to anonymize database from multiple different parties to get aggregated results

Tags: csv, cryptography

I will explain the problem using a simple example:

Alice has a CSV file with 2 columns: email and zipcode.

Bob has a CSV file with 2 columns: email and age.

The list of emails from both files are exactly the same. The goal is to get aggregated data from both files, for instance to know how many teenagers exist in a specific zipcode. The restrictions are:

- Bob cannot get or infer the zipcodes of each individual
- Alice cannot get or infer the ages of each individual
- No third party is allowed

I tried to think about double XOR encryption of the emails using a unique Key + random sort of the rows but this would be insecure as both Alice and Bob would use their single private key to encrypt all the emails.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have two other restrictions: 4. Both have to arrive at the same aggregated data. 5. If one cheats, the other should be able to tell. ... Anyway, this is not a programming question and is better suited for [crypto.se] with either multi-party computation or zero-knowledge proofs as tags. I doubt this is even answerable in the format of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [Homomorphic Encryption Scheme](https://www.google.com/search?q=Homomorphic+Encryption+Scheme). You can run queries on the encrypted data to limit what is revealed. Maybe the next best choice would be a [Format Preserving Encryption Scheme](https://www.google.com/search?q=Format+Preserving+Encryption+Scheme). Also see [AOL search data leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak). User 927 FTW!